# How to get rid of the createTheme warning from material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to get rid of the createTheme warning from material-ui

```
nodemon ./server-build/index.js
[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node ./server-build/index.js`
Material-UI: the createMuiTheme function was renamed to createTheme.
You should use `import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'`
```

Comment: Yes I did, but couldn't get rid of the warning

Answer (score 0):

Using an import statement like this removes the warning for me.

```
import createTheme from "@material-ui/core/styles/createTheme";
```

However, it does break my "no-restricted-imports" linting rule, so I'm still looking for a better answer.